# Accessing CCS pseudo-selectors using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am trying to set up a way of randomizing the header background image of a website so that whenever it is visited it will be different (with the obvious chance of it being the same if randomly selected). I have researched methods using jQuery, however the location of the background-image is in the pseudo-selector for the class, ::before.

```
#header-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: #080808 url("images/overlay.png") repeat;
    top: 0;
}

    #header-wrapper:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("images/foo.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        opacity: 0.35;
    }
```

As of right I have the `background-image:` to just one, but that what I'm hoping for is to include it among and array of other images.

Comment: I'd have to look it up but I'm pretty sure that jQuery does fine selecting pseudo-selectors, try `$("#header-wrapper:before")`?

Comment: Pseudo elements are not in the DOM and so are not accessible by Javascript